# Make use Pattern Rule for multiple prerequisites and multiple targets

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I have a problem with `make` and I cannot figure out how to solve it. I would like to transform each file in a sub-directory using a shell script. This is what I wrote:

```
OBJ=$(wildcard src/*.in)
OUT=$(patsubst %.in, %.out, $(notdir $(OBJ)))

%.out : src/%.in
    ./myscript.sh $< > $@

$(OUT) : $(OBJ)
```

The `makefile` works but it runs the script only for the first `.in` file and then it stops. Sorry for the dumb question but I cannot fix this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not telling the Makefile to build all `$(OUT)` files, you are just saying how it should be built.

Try instead this

```
OBJ=$(wildcard src/*.in)
OUT=$(patsubst %.in, %.out, $(notdir $(OBJ)))

all: $(OUT)

%.out : src/%.in
    ./myscript.sh $< > $@

.PHONY: all
```

Comment: So the `$(OUT) : $(OBJ)` is not enough! Thanks!

Comment: indeed, you need to say that you want to build all `$(OUT)`, not just how they should be built

Comment: I was thinking that the line `$(OUT) : $(OBJ)` would be enough but, reading the make manual more carefully, it turned out that make set the first rule as the goal of the makefile and if the goal has multiple targets, make will take only the first one! Correct me if I'm saying something wrong!